# Clojure Passing List Variables

Tags: list, clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to pass a list of variables into a function individually however when i try to pass them the function returns nill.

```
(map (partial shortestPath G) (first Robot)(second Robot))
```

I tested the bits of code individually and `(first Robot)` and `(second Robot)`
don't work as i intended them too they currently return and output like so`[[:space]]`.

What i need them to return is just `:Space`. How would i go about doing this?

Thanks.

Edit:

```
(def ItemPickUp [:Space :Mail])
(def ItemDestinations [:Storage :z2])
(def Robot [[ItemPickUp] [ItemDestinations]])
(map (partial shortestPath G) (first Robot)(second Robot))
```

Comment: We'll need more context than this.  This is related to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367877/clojure-passing-individual-variables-to-function) which doesn't include the ItemPickup or ItemDestinations code that produces this output.  Add those functions to this question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem i needed to use [flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten) like so

`(map (partial shortestPath G) (flatten (first Robot))(flatten(second Robot)))`

giving me the desired output

```
(flatten (first Robot))
(:Mail :d2)
```

Comment: `flatten` should be a last resort. Why are you using `flatten` here instead of `ffirst`, or instead of `(def Robot [ItemPickUp ItemDestinations])`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i am a novice at Clojure and i was trying to find a solution i was unaware of your solution which also works.

Comment: @noisesmith *`flatten`* (rather than Carthago) *delenda est* - the Cato of Clojure.